# Why is scipy.optimize.check_grad returning an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I have a model predicting house prices using regression.

For the exact solution, I have defined two functions to compute the mean squared error (mse) and the gradient of the error function (grad). Both of them are defined below:

```
def mse(theta,X,Y):
    Y_pred=np.dot(X,theta)
    dY=Y_pred-Y
    return 0.5*np.mean(dY**2)
def grad(theta,X,Y):
    Y_pred=np.dot(X,theta)
    dY=(Y_pred-Y)
    return (np.dot(X.T,dY)/len(X)).T
```

The inputs for the above are: X -> 7 features of the dataset. The dimensions would be 20640,7; Y -> the housing price to be predicted. The dimensions are 20640,1; theta -> Random variable generated using the following code

```
theta = np.random.normal(size=(7))
```

Now, when I use scipy.optimize.check_grad(mse,grad,theta,X,Y), it returns an array of size 7, instead of just giving me an expected output of the order 10^-7.

Why is this so, and how can I improve my code?

Comment: Not sure, but it might be that the size of Y should be (20640,) and not (20640,1). These are two different (confusing) things in numpy, namely a column vs. row vector, often leading to different results.

Comment: can you add the output from scipy.optimize.check_grad to your question?

Comment: @PV8 this is the Output - [-0.68804187 -0.1056183  -0.15194093  0.04669825  0.02464848  0.02373626
  0.14415329]

Comment: @Aguy that was my guess too. I tried reshaping it to (20640, ), but it still won't work.